# spring security oauth2 check_token using Xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to enable outh/check_token using but having some difficulty
according to this answer [How to enable /oauth/check_token with Spring Security Oauth2 using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629952/how-to-enable-oauth-check-token-with-spring-security-oauth2-using-xml)

You need to create a bean of type CheckTokenEndpoint. 
How do we do that I included this in my spring security.xml

```
<bean id="checkTokenEndpoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.CheckTokenEndpoint">
        <constructor-arg name="resourceServerTokenServices" ref="tokenServices"/>
    </bean>
```

this class `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.CheckTokenEndpoint` is throwing error

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Class 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.CheckTokenEndpoint' not found
    - Class 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.CheckTokenEndpoint' not found [config set: AuthenticationApp/web-
     context]
```

this is all the

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd ">
```

Can someone please help all the examples are using spring boot and java config but I have to do using xml config

Answer (score 1):

Use the last version of spring oauth2:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId
<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId
<version>2.0.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Ensure what the correct version of xsd is in use in spring security oauth file configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd>
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
```

Insert the option check-token-enabled="true" in the element authorization-server:

```
<oauth:authorization-server check-token-enabled="true" client-details-service-ref="jdbcClientDetailsService"/>
```