# Configuring resource server with RemoteTokenServices in Spring Security Oauth2

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement a authorization server and a resource server using spring security oauth2. So far i've managed to setup the authorization server and since i dont want to share a jdbc token store i'm trying to use the remoteTokenService to validate my tokens @ resource server. But i'm getting a 401 error every time i try to access a resource REST method.

I'm using xml configuration to setup spring security due to the nature of the project. I've tried with a another sample project using Javaconfig and its working fine.

Here are my configuration in the resource server.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>rest-project</display-name>
    <description>rest project Implementation</description>

    <!--
        - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
        - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!--
    - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-core-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

here is my security-config.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:oauth2="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
             xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd">



    <http pattern="/cards/**" use-expressions="true" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/cards/**" access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="https"/>
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
    </http>

    <oauth2:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="connector-bus" token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>

    <beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices">
        <beans:property name="checkTokenEndpointUrl" value="https://localhost:8443/auth-server/api/oauth/check_token"/>
        <beans:property name="clientId" value="123456" />
        <beans:property name="clientSecret" value="456"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


    <beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

    <beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />
</beans:beans>
```

Please point out what i'm missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

For some reason i couldn't get the xml configuration working to validate access tokens remotely. But I was able to setup oauth2 resource server using java config and it fixed the issue. Please find the code below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
public class Oauth2ResesourceServerConfiguration  extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(
                "https://localhost:8443/auth-server/oauth/check_token");
        tokenService.setClientId("client-id");
        tokenService.setClientSecret("client-secret");
        return tokenService;
    }



}
```

Comment: Do you know what the "tokenService()" method would be like in case we have many clients?

Answer (score 1):

`/oauth/check_token` must configure permission separately, it is 'denyAll' by default. If you add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` in properties, you can found the following logging lines:

```
2017-09-14 14:52:01.379  INFO 15591 --- [           main] b.a.s.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration : 
Using default security password: f1f7e508-4a30-4aad-914f-d0e90da6079a
2017-09-14 14:52:01.775 DEBUG 15591 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'fullyAuthenticated', for Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2017-09-14 14:52:01.872 DEBUG 15591 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'denyAll()', for Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key']
2017-09-14 14:52:01.879 DEBUG 15591 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'denyAll()', for Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']
```

I don't know how to permit it in xml, but by javaconfig as follow

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        // security.checkTokenAccess("permitAll");
    }
}
```

I found [How to enable /oauth/check_token with Spring Security Oauth2 using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38447330/7989206). Maybe help.

Answer (score 0):

along with making your tokenService method `@Primary` as told in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40626102/3044680 , form springboot 1.5 onwards add `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3` to application.properties

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to get this working simply through property config. Try putting this in your application.yml, along with your HttpSecurity config for the /cards/ URI.

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      token-info-uri: https://[your token validation endpoint]
      preferTokenInfo: true
```

Having @EnableWebSecurity and @EnableResourceServer is duplicative. You do not need @EnableWebSecurity.

Comment: It doesn't look like the user is using an `application.yml` file, the configuration is done in XML.