# Handle Security exceptions in Spring Boot Resource Server

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot, spring-security

How can I get my custom `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` or `OAuth2ExceptionRenderer` to handle Exceptions raised by Spring security on a pure resource server?

We implemented a

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
```

so whenever there is an error on the resource server we want it to answer with

```
{
  "message": "...",
  "type": "...",
  "status": 400
}
```

The resource server uses the application.properties setting:

```
security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri: http://localhost:9999/auth/user
```

to authenticate and authorize a request against our auth server.

However any spring security error will always bypass our exception handler at

```
    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidTokenException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> handleInvalidTokenException(InvalidTokenException e) {
        return createErrorResponseAndLog(e, 401);
    }
```

and produce either

```
{
  "timestamp": "2016-12-14T10:40:34.122Z",
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Access Denied",
  "path": "/api/templates/585004226f793042a094d3a9/schema"
}
```

or

```
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "5d7e4ab5-4a88-4571-b4a4-042bce0a076b"
}
```

So how do I configure the security exception handling for a resource server? All I ever find are examples on how to customize the Auth Server by implementing a custom `OAuth2ExceptionRenderer`. But I can't find where to wire this to the resource server's security chain.

Our only configuration/setup is this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"our.packages"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableResourceServer
```

Comment: Same question at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767267/handle-spring-security-authentication-exceptions-with-exceptionhandler?noredirect=1&lq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767267/handle-spring-security-authentication-exceptions-with-exceptionhandler?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: For OAuth2 exceptions, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45985310/2387977

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As noted in previous comments the request is rejected by the security framework before it reaches the MVC layer so `@ControllerAdvice` is not an option here.

There are 3 interfaces in the Spring Security framework that may be of interest here:

- org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler
- org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler
- org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler

You can create implementations of each of these Interfaces in order to customize the response sent for various events: successful login, failed login, attempt to access protected resource with insufficient permissions.

The following would return a JSON response on unsuccessful login attempt:

```
@Component
public class RestAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler
{
  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      AuthenticationException ex) throws IOException, ServletException
  {
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
    
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("timestamp", new Date());
    data.put("status",HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
    data.put("message", "Access Denied");
    data.put("path", request.getRequestURL().toString());
    
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(out, data);
    out.flush();
  }
}
```

You also need to register your implementation(s) with the Security framework. In Java config this looks like the below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("...")
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
  {
    http
       .addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
       .logout()
       .deleteCookies("JESSIONID")
       .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
       .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
       .and()
       .formLogin()
       .loginPage("/login")
       .loginProcessingUrl("/api/login")
       .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
       .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
       .and()
       .csrf()
       .disable()
       .exceptionHandling()
       .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
       .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
  }

  /**
   * @return Custom {@link AuthenticationFailureHandler} to send suitable response to REST clients in the event of a
   *         failed authentication attempt.
   */
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler()
  {
    return new RestAuthenticationFailureHandler();
  }

  /**
   * @return Custom {@link AuthenticationSuccessHandler} to send suitable response to REST clients in the event of a
   *         successful authentication attempt.
   */
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler()
  {
    return new RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
  }

  /**
   * @return Custom {@link AccessDeniedHandler} to send suitable response to REST clients in the event of an attempt to
   *         access resources to which the user has insufficient privileges.
   */
  @Bean
  public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler()
  {
    return new RestAccessDeniedHandler();
  }
}
```

Comment: In a pure `@EnableResourceServer` I have an `@Configuration` class where I wire in `http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(restAccessDeniedHandler`, however this doesn't catch the following:
`{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "5d7e4ab5-4a88-4571-b4a4-042bce0a076b"
}`

How would you do this?

Comment: In this answer, the `AuthenticationFailureHandler` is being wired in based on an `loginProcessingUrl`. I don't think you'd have one of those for an `@EnableResourceServer`. How else can you wire this in?

Comment: I have the same trouble as you . Can you find the final solution ? @p

Comment: I am facing issue. @peterl did you find solution to this?

Comment: You could also redirect the exception to the ControllerAdvice by injecting the HandlerExceptionResolver and then executing `resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, exception);` within the method `onAuthenticationFailure`. This centralizes your exception handling.

Answer (score 9):

In case if you're using `@EnableResourceServer`, you may also find convenient to extend `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` instead of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in your `@Configuration` class. By doing this, you may simply register a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` by overriding `configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)` and using `resources.authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthEntryPoint())` inside the method.

Something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class CommonSecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthEntryPoint());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthEntryPoint(){
        return new AuthFailureHandler();
    }
}
```

There's also a nice `OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint` that can be extended (since it's not final) and partially re-used while implementing a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. In particular, it adds "WWW-Authenticate" headers with error-related details.

Comment: It did not work for me where the security framework return "Invalid_token, token expired (blabla...the token string here)" .  It just the catch the exception of 401.

Answer (score 4):

You are not able to make use of Spring MVC Exception handler annotations such as `@ControllerAdvice` because spring security filters kicks in much before Spring MVC.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using token validation URL with config similar to [Configuring resource server with RemoteTokenServices in Spring Security Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40626102/5962766) which returns HTTP status 401 in case of unauthorized:

```
@Primary
@Bean
public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {
    RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
    tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("https://token-validation-url.com");
    tokenService.setTokenName("token");
    return tokenService;
}
```

Implementing custom `authenticationEntryPoint` as described in other answers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44372313/5962766) won't work because [RemoteTokenService](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/RemoteTokenServices.java) use 400 status and throws unhandled exceptions for other statuses like 401:

```
public RemoteTokenServices() {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ((RestTemplate) restTemplate).setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            // Ignore 400
            public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                if (response.getRawStatusCode() != 400) {
                    super.handleError(response);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

So you need to set custom `RestTemplate` in `RemoteTokenServices` config which would handle 401 without throwing exception:

```
@Primary
@Bean
public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {
    RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
    tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("https://token-validation-url.com");
    tokenService.setTokenName("token");
    RestOperations restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
    ((RestTemplate) restTemplate).setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            // Ignore 400 and 401
            public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                if (response.getRawStatusCode() != 400 && response.getRawStatusCode() != 401) {
                    super.handleError(response);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    tokenService.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
    return tokenService;
}
```

And add dependency for [HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53695761/5962766):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adapting the accepted answer for use with Spring `OAuth2ResourceServer` for JWT authentication, because without special configuration, it will register its own `BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint`, and ignore the one we set in `.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint()`

Hence, in our `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` we have:

```java
   @Autowired
   private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
                // ... all the usual stuff ...
                // configure OAuth2 (OIDC) JWT and set a custom authentication failure handler
                .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                        .jwt().and()
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationFailureHandler));
    }
```

where `AuthenticationFailureHandler` is coded as suggested in earlier answers:

```java
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    public AuthenticationFailureHandler() {
    }
    
    // Autowire our own CustomExceptionHandler: must be qualified because Spring Boot has others in the classpath
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver") 
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver; 

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws
            IOException {
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException);
    }
}
```

In our CustomExceptionHandler (which is autowired above, but not mentioned by class name explicitly) we add a method for AuthenticationException handling:

```java
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {AuthenticationException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<?> handleAuthenticationException(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {

        return ... something ... // create custom error response here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

OAuth2ExceptionRenderer is for an Authorization Server. The correct answer is likely to handle it like detailed in this post (that is, ignore that it's oauth and treat it like any other spring security authentication mechanism): https://stackoverflow.com/a/26502321/5639571

Of course, this will catch oauth related exceptions (which are thrown before you reach your resource endpoint), but any exceptions happening within your resource endpoint will still require an @ExceptionHandler method.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this security handler to pass the handler to spring mvc `@ControllerAdvice`

```
@Component
public class AuthExceptionHandler implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, AccessDeniedHandler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthExceptionHandler.class);

    private final HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    @Autowired
    public AuthExceptionHandler(@Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver") final HandlerExceptionResolver resolver) {
        this.resolver = resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        LOG.error("Responding with unauthorized error. Message - {}", authException.getMessage());
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        LOG.error("Responding with access denied error. Message - {}", accessDeniedException.getMessage());
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, accessDeniedException);
    }
}
```

Then define the exception by using `@ControllerAdvice` so  that we can manage the global exception handler in one place..

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Since the original question is for a REST controller that needs to return a custom JSON response, I will write up a complete answer step by step which worked for me. First and foremost, it seems you cannot handle this with a `@ControllerAdvice` that extends `ControllResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. You need a separate handler that extends `AccessDeniedHandler`. Follow the below steps.

#### Step 1: Create a custom handler class that extends `AccessDeniedHandler`

```
@Component
public class MyAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    private static final String JSON_TYPE = "application/json";
    
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                       AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException {
        MyErrorList errors = new MyErrorList();
        errors.addError(new MyError("", "You do not have permission to access this resource."));

        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
        response.setContentType(JSON_TYPE);
        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(output, errors);
        output.flush();
    }
}
```

'MyError' above is a simple POJO to represent an error json structure and MyErrorList is another POJO that holds a list of 'MyError's.

#### Step 2: Inject the Handler created above into the Security configuration

```
@Autowired
private VOMSAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;
```

#### Step 3: Register the `accessDeniedHandler` in your configure method

```
.and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
```

With **Step 2** and **Step 3**, Your `SecurityConfiguration` should look something like this (Note that I am omitting code that is not relevant to this problem to shorten the length of this answer):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    // Other stuff

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/public").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Spring 3.0 Onwards,You can use `@ControllerAdvice` (At Class Level) and extends `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class from `CustomGlobalExceptionHandler`

```
@ExceptionHandler({com.test.CustomException1.class,com.test.CustomException2.class})
public final ResponseEntity<CustomErrorMessage> customExceptionHandler(RuntimeException ex){
     return new ResponseEntity<CustomErrorMessage>(new CustomErrorMessage(false,ex.getMessage(),404),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```