# Spring Boot resource server validates token with HTTP POST instead of HTTP GET

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth

I have server with dependencies and config as it mentioned [Minimal OAuth2 Boot Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2-boot-resource-server-minimal):

- spring-security-oauth2
- spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure

Security config is annotated with `@EnableResourceServer`.

Properties contains:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resource:
        token-info-uri: https://token-validation-url/example
```

When I execute request `curl -H "Authorization: xyz" http://localhost:8080/my-endpoint`, I get 401 but I don't see that HTTP call for token validation would be executed.

If I remove spring prefix from the property, I still get 401 but it tries HTTP POST to `https://token-validation-url/example`:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      token-info-uri: https://token-validation-url/example
```

If I take the same token and try manually `HTTP GET https://token-validation-url/example?otoken=xyz`, it returns that it is valid.

How to specify `otoken` query param?
Why server tries to validate token with `HTTP POST` instead `HTTP GET`?

Comment: I don't know this exact example, but when I used spring security, I needed a valid token starting with Bearer in the header, like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265812/best-http-authorization-header-type-for-jwt

Comment: I pass it with Bearer, just missed in the example. I don't think that it causes a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noticed that `HTTP POST https://token-validation-url/example?otoken=xyz` validates the same as GET so used:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      token-info-uri: https://token-validation-url/example
```

Just needed to set token name:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
        RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices = context.getBean(RemoteTokenServices.class);
        remoteTokenServices.setTokenName("otoken");
    }
}
```

Other way to configure `RemoteTokenServices`: [Configuring resource server with RemoteTokenServices in Spring Security Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40626102/5962766)